# Trying to install karma in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js

Karma under nodejs using the npm fails and I don't have enough of an understanding of the technology to figure it out.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3Cuyw7h6

I ran:

```
npm install -g karma
```

as root.

Comment: From looking at the log, it looks like you didn't run the command as root. Are you sure you did?